# Monitering gpu stats of my onboard displays

Tags: monitoring, integrated-graphics

As the title says i want to be able to use msi or one of the windows gadjets to moniter my onboard display,

I currently use msi and a linked windows gadjet to monitor my pci card but want to be able to do this with an onboard gpu
Anybody know how or what i can use to do this.

thanks

Comment: "Monitor" how?  What are you monitoring?  Clockspeed? Load %? Temperatures?  All of the above?

Comment: This depends on the integrated graphics chip you have, and the statistics you want to monitor. For "integrated graphics" chips that are really just a discrete graphics chip soldered to the motherboard that shares system memory, OpenHardwareMonitor will probably do the trick. For integrated graphics technology that is a part of the processor (i.e. Intel HD Graphics), it gets trickier. If you have IHD Graphics, the temperature of your "graphics card" is the temp of your CPU; same for your fan etc. That's assuming you want to monitor temp and fan speed.

Comment: sorry i should of said its a intel hd so i guess long as my cpu is ok so should it 

thanks